# How can I count total selected row before apply LIMIT?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an almost complex query like this:

```
SELECT    qa.id, 
          qa.subject, 
          qa.category cat, 
          qa.keywords tags, 
          qa.body_html, 
          qa.amount, 
          qa.visibility, 
          qa.date_time, 
          COALESCE(u.reputation, 'N') reputation, 
          COALESCE(Concat(u.user_fname, ' ', u.user_lname), 'unknown') NAME, 
          COALESCE(u.avatar, 'anonymous.png') avatar, 
          ( 
                 SELECT COALESCE(Sum(vv.value),0) 
                 FROM   votes vv 
                 WHERE  qa.id = vv.post_id 
                 AND    15 = vv.table_code) AS total_votes, 
          ( 
                 SELECT COALESCE(Sum(vt.total_viewed),0) 
                 FROM   viewed_total vt 
                 WHERE  qa.id = vt.post_id 
                 AND    15 = vt.table_code limit 1) AS total_viewed 
FROM      qanda qa 
LEFT JOIN users u 
ON        qa.author_id = u.id 
AND       qa.visibility = 1 
WHERE     qa.type = 0 $query_where 
ORDER BY  $query_order
LIMIT     :j, 11;
```

Noted that `$query_where` variable contains some other conditions which will be created dynamically. Anyway, as you see, maximum it returns 10 posts.

Currently, to count total matched rows, I use another query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(amount) paid_qs,
       COUNT(*) all_qs
FROM qanda qa
WHERE type = 0 $query_where
```

I guess there is some waste processing. I mean two separated queries *(with complex conditions on the `where` clause)* will be too much.

Is there any approach to use one query instead of them?

Comment: Record how long your query takes to process, you might be surprised at how fast it is to do it twice.

Comment: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS with FETCH_ROWS() is another good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the found rows after the query with the `FOUND_ROWS()` function.

Reference: [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows)

You have to include the `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ...` clause into your query.

Comment: Well thanks you .. upvote. But honestly I'm not sure how can I use it. As you see, my second query counts two things: 1) all posts, 2) paid posts. How can I use your solution to do the same?

Comment: I guess it all depends on how many rows you have or how complex your query is, but I personally found this approach to be about 3 times slower than just using two queries.

Comment: @MartinAJ I see. I think you cannot spare the two queries here, because they yield two, absolutely different result set. I thought about subqueries, but that would not work either.

Comment: @WheatBeak Interesting. A `count(*)` is always very fast because it comes from table metadata on InnoDB (if I remember correctly), but if you apply conditions without indexing, it can be slow. I don't argue that the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ` may have problems, but this is the built-in solution of MySQL. Anyway, it is worth to measure, because all depends on the actual implementation (even it may be different for the OP).

Comment: Well like I said it was just in my particular personal experience with only moderately complex queries and on tables with <10,000 rows.

Comment: @WheatBeak I meant that even the same table with same number of rows and same query may perform differently on a different MySQL/InnoDB version, different hardware, different setup. Your approach may perform better than the built-in solution.